# How to convert yii view page into pdf and download it?

Tags: php, yii

This is my view page that i want to download as pdf. My view link: http://localhost/myproject/Applicant/1

[image]

I want to put a download PDF button at the right top of that page, When i click on it, The user profile should be downloaded in PDF. Im new to yii so not sure how to do it, But by searching on google, i found some extensions.

- yii-pdf
- mpdf1

by following these above extensions, I put those extensions in my `protected/extension` folder. Then Here is my main/config file..

```
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'class' => 'WebUser',
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        'returnUrl'=>'/site/index#login',
        'loginUrl'=>array('/Applicant/login'),
    ),
    'ePdf' => array(
        'class'         => 'ext.yii-pdf.EYiiPdf',
        'params'        => array(
            'mpdf'     => array(
                'librarySourcePath' => 'application.extensions.mpdf.*',
                'constants'         => array(
                    '_MPDF_TEMP_PATH' => Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.runtime'),
                ),
                'class'=>'mpdf', // the literal class filename to be loaded from the vendors folder
                /*'defaultParams'     => array( // More info: http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=184
                    'mode'              => '', //  This parameter specifies the mode of the new document.
                    'format'            => 'A4', // format A4, A5, ...
                    'default_font_size' => 0, // Sets the default document font size in points (pt)
                    'default_font'      => '', // Sets the default font-family for the new document.
                    'mgl'               => 15, // margin_left. Sets the page margins for the new document.
                    'mgr'               => 15, // margin_right
                    'mgt'               => 16, // margin_top
                    'mgb'               => 16, // margin_bottom
                    'mgh'               => 9, // margin_header
                    'mgf'               => 9, // margin_footer
                    'orientation'       => 'P', // landscape or portrait orientation
                )*/
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

I have created this action in ApplicantController

```
public function actionPDF()
{
    $mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf();
    $mPDF1->WriteHTML($this->render('UserProfileView',true));
    $mPDF1->Output();
}
```

What should i do next? how to get the button on that view file which is link to controller action to download file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit your form to an action.

for example, in your view:

```
<?php echo CHtml::button('Button Text', array('submit' => array('controller/action'))); ?>
```

In here the button will call the action in controller and execute what need to be done in that action.

> **EDITED**

If I'm right, you are rendering protected/views/applicant/view.php  so you can add in the sidebar the link to you action:

```
<?php
/* @var $this ApplicantController */
/* @var $model Applicant*/

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
  'Applicant'=>array('index'),
   $model->id,
);

$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'List Applicant', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('label'=>'Create Applicant', 'url'=>array('create')),
    array('label'=>'Create PDF', 'url'=>array('PDF')),
```

Don't forget adding to rules in your ApplicantController.php:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view','PDF'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
```

Comment: Not sure what do u mean exactly, I don't have a form, Im getting information from database tables for users, and displaying in view page in table..